# Multi-stage Dockerfile not working for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

Currently I am creating a virtual environment in the first stage.
Running command `pip install -r requirements.txt` , which install executables in `/venv/bin dir`.

In second stage i am copying the `/venv/bin dir` , but on running the python app error comes as module not found i.e i need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` again to run the app . 
The application is running in python 2.7 and some of the dependencies requires compiler to build . Also those dependencies are failing with alpine images compiler , and only works with ubuntu compiler or python:2.7 official image ( which in turn uses debian)

Am I missing some command in the second stage that will help in using the copied dependencies instead of installing it again .

```
FROM python:2.7-slim AS build
RUN apt-get update &&apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
COPY ./requirements.txt /project/requirements/
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -r /project/requirements/requirements.txt
COPY . /venv/bin

FROM python:2.7-slim AS release
COPY --from=build /venv /venv
WORKDIR /venv/bin
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc
#RUN pip install -r requirements.txt //
RUN cp settings.py.sample settings.py
CMD ["/venv/bin/python3", "-m", "main.py"]
```

I am trying to avoid `pip install -r requirements.txt` in second stage to reduce  the image size which is not happening currently.

Comment: Please include the commands you are running and their output.

Comment: In my Python images I usually follow the same approach, but instead of using the full path to the binary in the virtualenv, I modify the `PATH`. Check if that approach works out for you: https://github.com/eez0/docker-samples/blob/master/Dockerfile_python

Comment: Thanks, i tried running your dockerfile but in second image no module was installed. to debug the issue i went inside the image python main.py so no modules are present . i had to do again pip install -r requirements.txt in second image .

Comment: Also can you tell what in general your image size is ?

Comment: Only copying the `bin` dir isn't enough; for example, packages are installed in `lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` and headers under `include`.

Answer (score 1):

Only copying the `bin` dir isn't enough; for example, packages are installed in `lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` and headers under `include`. I'd just copy the whole venv directory. You can also run it with `--no-cache-dir` to avoid saving the wheel archives.

Answer (score -1):

insert before all

```
FROM yourimage:tag AS build
```

Comment: it was typo , i am doing that actually